# How do I highlight a table row when checkbox is selected? Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, angular7

So let's skip the the table headers to my table body. I have a populated table:

HTML:

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let e of emails; let i = index">
   <td <input type="checkbox" id="email-checkbox" (change)="addToSelectedList($event, e)"></input></td>
   <td id="subject-{{i}}">{{e.sender}}</td>
   <td id="subject-{{i}}">{{e.subject}}</td>
   <td id="subject-{{i}}">{{e.date}}</td>
</tbody>
```

I want the table whole row to display a CSS class when the user checks the checkbox. And then the color should go back to normal when the user deselects. Just UI stuff to show the user that an email has been selected. I currently have an empty CSS and .ts file.

Comment: You could experiment with `[ngClass]="selectedElementClass(e)"`, where the method returns the class string that should be put on the `tr`.  https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: You're really close. You already have your *change* **event** giving you a bool I assume you've got storing to a public var or something right? Now just use it in connection with [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). However use the basic `{'classname' : booleanVar}` format instead of a method to set it for perf reasons.

Comment: @ChrisW.  So this works except that instead of applying the class on the specific index of the selected tr, it highlights all the table rows in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have done it here is more involved because presumably you have some logic inside addToSelectedList event that will add/remove the email depending on the checked state. The easiest way is to add a property on the email entity isSelected, and do this:

```
<input  ... [checked]="e.isSelected" >
```

On your tr add the ngclass binding as suggested by others as follows:

```
<tr [ngClass]="{ 'selectedcssclass' : e.isSelected }"...
```

Other observation in your code there isn't a closing tr that should be wrapping around all the tds.

Comment: Another observation is the input is repeating with the same id, but ya this is closer.

Comment: Thank you very much and yes, you're right about the logic inside addToSelectedList event.

Answer (score 0):

Not an Angular expert, but you can achieve just that using a JS `onchange` event bound to your checkbox:

```js
$(".box").on("change", function() {
   $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Label 1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="box"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Label 2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="box"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```